# SQL getting items not in a list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and I have a list of emails from a spreadsheet that I inserted into a query against a user table. Out of 821 emails in the list, it returned 759 rows. Is there any easy way to get it to return those emails not in the table? I only have read access to the database so cannot create a table with the email list - only get results. Here is a simplified version of the query I used to get the list of those emails that were there:

```
select *
from UserTbl
where username in ('email1','email2','email3',...'email821')
```

I could come up with a Unix shell solution, but it would be far more useful to know how to do it in MS SQL. I actually found something close to a solution from stackoverflow ("T-SQL: How to Select Values in Value List that are NOT IN the Table?") , but it did not seem to work for me (for my needs I would only want a list of those not in the table output):

```
SELECT username,
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UsersTbl tu WHERE E.email = tu.username) THEN 'Exist'
        ELSE 'Not Exist'
    END AS
FROM (VALUES('email1'),('email2'),('email3'),('email4')) E(email)
```

This gave me the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'" when I run the query. As an aside, I was googling looking around for a description of the VALUES keyword used above and didn't find anything helpful on it.

If anyone could help me out on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 18):

If you just want the list of e-mails that aren't already present, this seems much simpler:

```
SELECT e.email
FROM 
(
  VALUES('email1'),('email2'),('email3'),('email4')
) AS e(email)
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.UsersTbl 
    WHERE username = e.email
);
```

Or even simpler:

```
SELECT e.email 
FROM 
(
  VALUES('email1'),('email2'),('email3'),('email4')
) AS e(email)
EXCEPT
SELECT username FROM dbo.UsersTbl;
```

To see why I prefer `NOT EXISTS` / `EXCEPT` over `LEFT JOIN` or other alternatives, see:

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Answer (score 4):

seems that you're just missing an alias after the "AS"

```
SELECT username,
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UsersTbl tu WHERE E.email = tu.username) THEN 'Exist'
        ELSE 'Not Exist'
    END AS doesExist
FROM (VALUES('email1'),('email2'),('email3'),('email4')) E(email)
```

Answer (score 3):

What you had was very close, you just needed to actually specify the alias for the second column. Also, I think you want to select `E.email`, not the null `username` column (if you were to join back on the table)

```
SELECT E.email,
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UsersTbl tu WHERE E.email = tu.username) THEN 'Exist'
        ELSE 'Not Exist'
    END AS ex
FROM (VALUES('email1'),('email2'),('email3'),('email4')) E(email)
```

Although, to get the list of emails that were not imported, I would probably just do:

```
SELECT E.email
FROM (VALUES('email1'),('email2'),('email3'),('email4')) E(email)
LEFT OUTER JOIN UsersTbl tu ON E.email = tu.username
WHERE tu.username IS NULL
```

Or,

```
SELECT E.email
FROM (VALUES('email1'),('email2'),('email3'),('email4')) E(email)
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM UsersTbl tu 
    WHERE E.email = tu.username
)
```

Comment: On both versions I get the error "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'." Does VALUES allow the  the list to be treated like a table?

Comment: @BanAtman Your question was tagged as SQL Server 2008. Are you sure you're on SQL Server 2008 (or better)?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  10.50.2500.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)  6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML     3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer   8.0.7601.17514
Microsoft .NET Framework   2.0.50727.5466
Operating System    6.1.7601

Comment: @BanAtman Does `select * from (values('foo')) bar(baz)` work?

Comment: @BanAtman Are you sure you are looking at the properties of the server instead of your computer?.

Comment: I get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'values'" for your simplified example as well (select * from (values('foo')....). The properties I listed were from the Help/About window where I click on the copy info. button.

Comment: @BanAtman Well I can verify the syntax works on both SQLFiddle and my instance of SQL Server 2012. I wonder if the server you're connecting to is truly 2008... If you can't use the `VALUES()` derived table syntax you can create a temp table, insert all the values you expect and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fully automate it, would be to use your spreadsheet as a database using an openrowset. However, openrowset might not be allowed and your excel file need to be on the server or accessible through a network path.

[Here is a great tutorial I have found Spreadsheet http://www.sql-programmers.com/tsql-openrowset-in-sql-server.aspx](http://www.sql-programmers.com/tsql-openrowset-in-sql-server.aspx)

```
Declare @UserTbl Table
(
    email nVarchar(255),
    firstname nVarchar(255),
    lastname nVarchar(255)
)

INSERT into @UserTbl VALUES('user1@email.com','User','1')
INSERT into @UserTbl VALUES('user2@email.com','User','2')
INSERT into @UserTbl VALUES('user3@email.com','User','3')

select *
from @UserTbl
where email not in (SELECT Email FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;Database=C:\email.xls;HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [Feuil1$]')
)

-- Sample to read a file from Excel     SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;Database=C:\email.xls;HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [Feuil1$]')
```

Comment: I tried this but don't have permissions to access a file like that. I did modify your example though by writing a quick Unix routine to output all the INSERT into @UserTbl... lines (822 of them) and pasted it into MS SQL Server:
`Declare @UserTbl Table (email nVarchar(255));INSERT into @UserTbl VALUES('.......... etc.
select * from @UserTbl
where email not in (select username from TblUser)
`
and it worked. If TblUser also had a field called email, how would I access the one from @TblUser as doing @TblUser.email didn't work?

Comment: If you have a common email field what you can do is `select * from @UserTbl ut join @TblUser tu On tu.email = ut.email and tu.username is null`